# Why successive deletes are taking increased time?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I have a table(say `tableB`) with around 40M rows (always increasing). The archiving is currently done by `DELETE .. OUTPUT .. INTO .. FROM ..` way. For archiving 1000 rows it took 3~5 seconds
initially. But as more rows are being deleted, it is taking more time. For example, after deleting 10M rows, it is now taking 35~40 seconds to 
delete 1000 rows.

What is causing this? 
How can I improve the situation (I need to archive at least 30M rows)?
If partitioning is the only way how can I do that with minimal down time?

Other info:

- `tableB` has 2 foreign key columns (`tableAId`, `tableCId`)
- Archiving is being performed based on a date-time field in `tableA` (an `inner-join` is being used in the `DELETE` statement)
- The query plan shows 81% cost on the inner-join
- If I use query hint `with (index=ix_time)` for `tableA`, the plan shows 100% cost on index-seek for the index on the foreign key coloumn of `tableB`
- Both `tableA` and `tableB` has auto-incrementing `bigint` as primary key.
- `tableB` has 4 indices
- `tableA` has 5 indices
- `tableA` has 30M+ rows.
- Indices/stats are being rebuilt/reorganized/updated every-day
- SQL Server 2008R2
- Windows Server 2008R2, 16 cores, 32G RAM
- I am an *accidental dba* atm

Query plan excerpt:

[image: Query plan excerpt:]

The script:

```
DECLARE @older_than datetime2(0) = '2015-10-01';
DECLARE @i int = 1;
DECLARE @j int = 0;
DECLARE @imax int = 1000;
DECLARE @jmax int = 50;
DECLARE @total int = 0;
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME2(3);
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME2(3);
DECLARE @timetook int;

WHILE @i > 0 AND @j < @jmax
BEGIN
    SET @t1 = GETDATE();
    DELETE TOP (@imax) ss   
        OUTPUT  deleted.[Id]    
          ,deleted.[columnA]
          ,deleted.[columnB]          

        INTO [MyArchive_Data].dbo.tableB([Id]
          ,columnA
          ,columnB)

    FROM [MyLive_Data].dbo.tableB ss
    INNER JOIN [MyLive_Data].dbo.tableA s ON s.Id = ss.tableAID

    WHERE s.Time < @older_than;
    SET @i = @@rowcount;
    SET @j = @j + 1;
    SET @total = @total + @i;
    SET @t2 = GETDATE();
    SET @timetook = datediff(second,@t1,@t2);
    RAISERROR('LOOP %d COMPLETE [%d rows][%d sec]',10,1,@j, @total, @timetook) with nowait;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03';
END
```

**Update**

It seems that if I exclude the loop construct (`WHILE @i > 0 AND @j < @jmax`) and run only the DELETE statement separately, it takes 10~12 seconds. I observed the query plans. Those were different. With the loop construct ON, it used `index-seek` but without it, `index-scan` was being used. Why?

Comment: Can you post your `DELETE` statement?

Comment: Try disabling indexes when doing delete operation as indexes can degrade the delete performance as SQL server has to update indexes after each delete.

Comment: @Felix Pamittan: Script posted

Comment: @Harsh: Not an option

Comment: You're using `TOP` without `ORDER BY`. Is that intended?

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Yes.

Comment: Instead of deleting with TOP, consider deleting by ID ranges in addition to your time criteria.  I would expect that would provide a seek instead of scan.

Comment: What is Table A size?

Comment: @DanGuzman: scan/seek is only 4% of the cost. 81% cost is for the merge-join. If I use query hint, it is a seek; but then, 100% cost is for the seek.

Comment: @Eric: Table A size is over 30M.

Comment: Your screenshot got cutoff so I don't see the *Actual* lines. Since the arrows going into the Merge Join are pretty thin, I think the problem may be elsewhere (yes, execution plans can lie!). Find any fat arrows, key lookup warning sides, or anything where it shows a huge discrepancy between *Expected* vs. *Actual*.

Comment: Surprise: If I exclude the loop constraint `WHILE @i > 0 AND @j < @jmax` it comes down to 10~12 sec (instead of 40). I observed the query plan. To my surprise, the query plans are different. With the loop construct on, it uses index-seek. But without it, it uses index-scan(faster). Question is, WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full table schema with indexes I'd say that SQL server query optimizer is finding that it's more efficient to scan the clustered index because the statistics on the table shows a correlation between the values of ID and Time to know that if it starts at the end of the clustered index and processes it in reverse order the it will have to read less rows to find TOP(x) rows that satisfy the query.  [Brent Ozar's post on Scans, Seeks and Statistics](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/05/seeks-scans-and-statistics-grocery-store/)

Also you have the `WAITFOR` statement in the loop which is probably causing lock escalations on the table as the delete is being done in an implicit transaction so only once the loop ends will the deletes be committed. Try adding a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before the delete statement and a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` right after it.  And if all possible remove the `WAITFOR` statement as it's causing delays in processing.

```
DECLARE @older_than datetime2(0) = '2015-10-01';
DECLARE @i int = 1;
DECLARE @j int = 0;
DECLARE @imax int = 1000;
DECLARE @jmax int = 50;
DECLARE @total int = 0;
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME2(3);
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME2(3);
DECLARE @timetook int;

WHILE @i > 0 AND @j < @jmax
BEGIN
SET @t1 = GETDATE();
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
DELETE TOP (@imax) ss   
    OUTPUT  deleted.[Id]    
      ,deleted.[columnA]
      ,deleted.[columnB]          

    INTO [MyArchive_Data].dbo.tableB([Id]
      ,columnA
      ,columnB)

FROM [MyLive_Data].dbo.tableB ss
INNER JOIN [MyLive_Data].dbo.tableA s ON s.Id = ss.tableAID

WHERE s.Time < @older_than;
COMMIT TRANSACTION 
SET @i = @@rowcount;
SET @j = @j + 1;
SET @total = @total + @i;
SET @t2 = GETDATE();
SET @timetook = datediff(second,@t1,@t2);
RAISERROR('LOOP %d COMPLETE [%d rows][%d sec]',10,1,@j, @total, @timetook) with nowait;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03';
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that I expect will be more efficient for very large archive processing.  This method deletes in batches by ID range rather than TOP.  You can tweak the batch size according to your performance and concurrency needs.

```
DECLARE
      @older_than datetime2(0) = '2015-10-01'
    , @i int = 1
    , @j int = 0
    , @total int = 0
    , @t1 DATETIME2(3)
    , @t2 DATETIME2(3)
    , @timetook int
    , @MinID int
    , @MaxId int
    , @BatchFirstId int
    , @BatchLastId int
    , @BatchSize int =100000;
SELECT @MinID = MIN(Id), @MaxID = MAX(Id) FROM dbo.TableA;
SET @BatchFirstId = @MinID;
WHILE @BatchFirstId <=  @MaxId
BEGIN

    SET @BatchLastID = @BatchFirstId + @BatchSize - 1;
    SET @t1 = GETDATE();
    DELETE ss   
        OUTPUT  deleted.[Id]    
          ,deleted.[columnA]
          ,deleted.[columnB]          

        INTO [MyArchive_Data].dbo.tableB([Id]
          ,columnA
          ,columnB)

    FROM [MyLive_Data].dbo.tableB ss
    INNER JOIN [MyLive_Data].dbo.tableA s ON s.Id = ss.tableAID
    WHERE s.Time < @older_than
        AND s.Id BETWEEN @BatchFirstID AND @BatchLastID;

    SET @i = @@ROWCOUNT;
    SET @BatchFirstId += @BatchSize;
    SET @j = @j + 1;
    SET @total = @total + @i;
    SET @t2 = GETDATE();
    SET @timetook = datediff(second,@t1,@t2);
    RAISERROR('LOOP %d COMPLETE [%d rows][%d sec]',10,1,@j, @total, @timetook) with nowait;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03';

END;
```